# Getting the title of a pressed/clicked UItableview cell

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

Okay so I have a view controller with about 5 UITableView Cells inside it. They are all static. What i want to do is click on "Cell One" and then load the "Cell One" PDF. Right now I have it set up with segues in my storyboard so that if you click "Cell One" or "Cell Two" they all open the same PDF. That PDF is loaded in another UIWebView view although i dont know if that matters. So basically can somone help me figure out how I can get the title of the cell that was clicked? Thank you!

Comment: In `didSelectRowAtIndex`, do `UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView cellAtIndexPath:indexPath]`; and get the title of it with `[cell title]` ? Show the code of the next controller also.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your `didSelectRowAtIndex:` method you want to do this:

```
UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
NSString *cellTitle = [[cell textLabel] text];
```

Now you're cell title will be in the `cellTitle` `NSString`.

This assumes you haven't used a custom cell. If you have then you just ref your custom label i.e.

```
YOURCUSTOMCELLCLASS *cell = (YOURCUSTOMCELLCLASS *)[tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
NSString *cellTitle = [[cell CUSTOMLABEL] text];
```